# Concatenate unicode and utf-8 Python 2.7

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, concatenation

```
>>> dir = u'\\\\nas\\cut\\'
>>> cutter = "seleção"
>>> ext = ".cf2"
>>> path = dir+cutter+ext

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    path = dir+cutter+ext
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is needed to use:

```
f = open(dir, 'r')
```

I don't know how I concatenate this well. The variable dir must be in unicode because I use configparser to parse te value from a .ini file and that comes with unicode encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Decode your bytes to a `unicode` string, explicitly:

```
path = dir + cutter.decode('utf8') + ext.decode('utf8')
```

Note that you should really use the `os.path.join()` function to build paths:

```
path = os.path.join(dir, cutter.decode('utf8') + ext.decode('utf8'))
```

This assumes you know your terminal or console is configured for UTF-8; it is better to use `sys.stdin.encoding` here. For data sourced from elsewhere, determine the codec for that source first.

Comment: What if his terminal isn't UTF-8? :)

Comment: @MarkTolonen good point; I did make an assumption there based on the tags. Using `sys.stdin.encoding` would be the better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

If your filename and extension are constants like your example, just use Unicode strings for everything:

```
>>> dir = u'\\\\nas\\cut\\'
>>> cutter = u"seleção"
>>> ext = u".cf2"
>>> path = dir+cutter+ext
```

If not constants and they are byte strings, `.decode()` them with an appropriate encoding.  What that encoding is will be OS-dependent.

Note that some APIs like `os.listdir()` and `glob.glob()` can take a Unicode argument and return Unicode strings.